# Assign an attribute to a TObject in Delphi

Tags: delphi

Is it possible to assign an attribute to a TObject in Delphi? So I can later use it for something?

For example, I'm creating a menu, and I want an item from the menu to have a `isActive` property, so I can check it later for styling.

Is this possible?

Something like:

```
Object.setAttribute('isActive', true);
```

Comment: Some options: 1. Derive a subclass of the menu class that you use and add the new property. 2. Reuse an existing property (e.g. Tag) that is otherwise not used. 3. Store the information in a separate place, e.g. a dictionary which would allow you to query whether or not a specific item has the attribute.  Of these options the final one would seem to me, given the information that we have, to be the best.

Comment: I'm curious to understand what it means for a menu to be active. Could you elaborate? Perhaps the information is already maintained by the system.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan it means the section that that menu references is open now. I want to do for example what you would do in HTML+JS: `element.setAttribute('attrName', 'attrValue')` and then you can get it using `element.getAttribute('attrName')`

Comment: Normally in Windows you'd handle an event that was fired when the menu was dropped down. Further, in Windows menus a run out of a modal message loop so the only code of yours that runs is in response to notification messages (often surfaced as events).

Comment: The strict answer is 'no'. Objects in Delphi are not as lego-like as in JavaScript. But there are all kinds of ways around it, like subsclassing (already proposed) or the `Tag` property that every TComponent descendant has, although that's a slippery slope. The best solution, already very opinion based, mainly depends on context that was not given in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Delphi knows class helpers you can use to add functionality to existing class.
You can try for example:

```
TObjectHelper = class helper for TObject
private
  function GetMyProp: string;
  procedure SetMyProp(const Value: string);
public
  property myprop:string read GetMyProp write SetMyProp;
end;
```

Note I find sub-classing is a more logical way to go about it.